# Highcharts - Is it possible to have marker visible only in navigator, and not visible in main chart?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to have marker visible only in navigator, and not visible in main chart?

The way I am adding point looks like this:

```
series.addPoint({
    x: timestamp, 
    y: value, 
    marker: {
            enabled: true,
            symbol: 'url(assets/icons/marker.png)',
            height: 25,
            width: 25,
        },
});
```

They are visible both in main chart and in navigator area:

[image: This is how it looks now]

I'd like them to be visible only in navigator area.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addPoint` method on the series in navigator:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var navigatorSeries = this.series[1];

                navigatorSeries.addPoint({
                    x: 3,
                    y: 6,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)',
                        height: 25,
                        width: 25
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null, 6, 7]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/75390Lr4/